# Problema com ng-click + menu AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, menu

Tenho um menu que é preenchido de modo dinâmico:

```
<div ng-controller="menuDinamicoController as vm">
  <div ng-show="isAutenticado">
    <img src="{{vm.fotoUser}}" id="imagemUsuario" width="50px" />
    <label id="nomeUsuario" ng-model="nomeUser">{{vm.nomeUser}}</label>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in menu">
                <a href="{{x.Link}}" ng-click="vm.{{x.Id}}()">{{x.Nome}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A estrutura do link está sendo retornada corretamente:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.sair()" class="ng-binding">Sair</a>
```

Na minha controller tenho a seguinte função:

```
vm.sair = function () {
        $cookieStore.remove("Usuario");
        $cookieStore.remove("Token");
        $location.path("/");
};
```

Porém, o ng-click não está chamando a função.E o seguinte erro ocorre: 
***Syntax Error: Token 'x.Id' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].***

Comment: Não sei se será possível dessa maneira pois o ng-click não espera as chaves (ng-click="vm.{{x.Id}}()") que usou para preencher o Id, aí ele se confunde na hora de executar a chamada da função. Vou fazer uns testes aqui, se conseguir algo te aviso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira que pode funcionar é a seguinte:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in menu">
    <a href="{{x.Link}}" ng-click="vm.runFunction(x.Id)">{{x.Nome}}</a>
</li>
```

Em seu controller (exemplo em coffee script, vc pode converter para javascript se quiser):

```
runFunction: (id)->
    if 'sair' == id
      @sair()
```

Não sei se é muito gambiarra fazer isto mas usei em um caso específico aqui e funcionou certinho.

Dê uma olhada neste [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cdaringe/FNky4/1/) também. Se usar esta lógica no ng-repeat ao invés do select acredito que também funcione.

Comment: Desse jeito funcionou. Testei uma outra forma, utilizando apenas ng-click="vm[x.Id]()" e obtive o mesmo resultado. Obrigada !

Comment: Quando a resposta resolver seu problema, clique em aceitar a resposta por favor, facilita a visualização da solução do problema para quem precisar, muito obrigado.